# Apple Reedem Code Installs Different Apps

Tags: ios, xamarin, in-house-distribution

We have in-house app developed with Xamarin. Distribution of app is reedem codes via App Store. Everything is ok, we can distributed our in-house app with reedem codes generated in Apple Developer Program. When some clients enters reedem codes on App Store to install app, different app(s) which we did not develop are installed and we want to know why? I googled the problem but there was no result or solution. I just want to know the reason. If anyone faced with this problem and knows why please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a reedem code bug unfotunately. You just need to delete different apps. And use new one.